# How to change URL structure with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have downloaded and installed http://www.question2answer.org/ on my website on http://www.yourstartups.com/discussion/ (discussion sub-directory)

Current url structure is like: example.com/index.php?qa=123&qa_1=why-do-birds-sing
I want to change to /123/why-do-birds-sing
(why-do-birds-sing is example query)

Following is my htaccess:

```html
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need a new rule to rewrite your pretty URL.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?qa=$1&qa_1=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?qa-rewrite=$0 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```