# URL structure change using .htaccess rule

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, query-string

I have no knowledge in regex and never done regex redirections.
htaccess
but... I am looking for a way to redirect this URL structure:
http://www.example.com/mypage/param1/
to this URL structure
http://www.example.com/mypage/?key1=param1
and, if possible, only if param1 contains @ or %40

I saw this answer:
[How to change URL structure with htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26303110/how-to-change-url-structure-with-)
but that's the reveresed direction for my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 @
RewriteRule ^mypage/((?!index).+)$ /mypage/?key=$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Remove the R flag if you dont want the url to change.

This will redirect an url of the form :

```
/mypage/.*@.*
```

to

```
/mypage/?key=.*@.*
```